# Internet connection at a shop 150' from the house without extra wiring

Tags: internet

The shop is connected to the The house is connected with the shop by a 10/2 underground wire running 20 A, 220 V. At the shop I have a small breaker box to break it down into two 110 V circuits.

Is there a way to run internet through the home wiring that goes to the shop?

Comment: There might be but off-topic here.

Comment: Powerline communication is what you are looking for, I guess. Search for "Homeplug".

Comment: Is the AC power line in a conduit?  (also how did you get 120/240V out of /2 cable, you aren't doubling up neutral and ground are you? That would be bad)...

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking at a directional wifi extender. These are wifi extenders that are designed to cover a sector instead of a roughly spherical area. I see these often in airport environments. 150' might be a bit too long for conventional powerline internet, though don't let that stop you from trying it.

Comment: (Downvoters please comment *what* makes the post so voted *not useful*.)

Comment: @greybeard Experienced users will already know that answers to off-topic questions may be downvoted. Other users have next-to-no-chance of finding that information, which seems to be how "they" want it to be. (Expect this comment to disappear as soon as "they" see it :) )